# Android Dialog setMultiChoiceItems - ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, dialog

I want to create Dialog with multi choice items like on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

The only problem is, that I'm getting ArrayList from MySQL database wih PHP, so i can't provide resource id, like it's requested. Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("")
           .setMultiChoiceItems(db.getProjetky(), null, //the first argument needs to be resource id (int)
                      new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() 
              .......
```

db.getProjekty();

```
public ArrayList<String> getProjetky() {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", get_project_tag));
    ArrayList<String> projekty = jsonParser.getProjektyArrayFromUrl(URL,params);
    return projekty; //returns ArrayList<String> 
    }
```

Comment: can you put code sample which will clear things?

Comment: edited (character limit...)

Comment: You can try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865242/how-to-get-setmultichoiceitems-checkboxes-in-dialogs-to-update-when-you-use-a-sq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of strings, as written in the [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems(java.lang.CharSequence[],%20boolean[],%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener)):

> public AlertDialog.Builder setMultiChoiceItems (CharSequence[] items,
>   boolean[] checkedItems, DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener
>   listener)
>
> Added in API level 1 Set a list of items to be displayed in the dialog
>   as the content, you will be notified of the selected item via the
>   supplied listener. The list will have a check mark displayed to the
>   right of the text for each checked item. Clicking on an item in the
>   list will not dismiss the dialog. Clicking on a button will dismiss
>   the dialog.